# Using Ionic application as web app

Tags: ionic-framework

Can I build an ionic application and use it as web application with full capabilities as the mobile part ? Or ionic have 100% efficiency on phones ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for running ionic on as a web application. yes you can do that. but one thing you'll need to consider when developing your application. check your dependencies and libraries, and be sure that they support web application. else you should be fine.
As for the efficiency part, it is not optimal, but you can enhance the performance. something that ionic does that will slow your app is loading all your application in one JS file, that delays the lunch, to avoid that use lazy loading to load your app's components.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: My team needs to work in the field using the app. And then gets back to the office and handle the data using either mobile app or a web app on laptops. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: im glad it was helpful.